# Will subclassing reduce my duplicate code?

Tags: swift, class, model-view-controller, abstraction

**Update: More code added

My controller is calling my primary class Exercise to get values based on my data model.  The data model contains a number of other classes that do calculations and contain data structure objects for the primary class.  I feel like I have to do a lot of code duplication such as Exercise.getLastWorkout() which then calls my WorkoutDiary.getLastWorkout() to actually retrieve the workout.

Technically everything works fine, but I feel like I am missing a concept of abstraction.  Could subclassing help me by providing inherited functions?

My code is here: https://github.com/briancl2/WorkoutTracker/tree/master/Workout%20Tracker

A good place to look is here for my controller that I request values from my model: https://github.com/briancl2/WorkoutTracker/blob/master/Workout%20Tracker/ExerciseDetailViewController.swift

And this is the interface to my model:
https://github.com/briancl2/WorkoutTracker/blob/master/Workout%20Tracker/Exercise.swift

The model calls on a number of other classes to create necessary data structures within it (WorkoutDiary) and perform calculations (PerformanceAnalyzer).

The WorkoutDiary class calls on other classes for relevant data structures as well (Workout, which calls on Set... so the abstraction continues)

Is this a proper design paradigm?  I am building this app as a learning experience, so I recognize I am over-engineering such a simple app (tracking workouts).  That is my intention.  However, I want to get the design principles right.

```
class Exercise: NSObject, NSCoding {
    var name: String
    var notes: String?
    private var workoutDiary = WorkoutDiary(diary: [])
    var currentWeights = Weights(heavy: 0)

init(name: String, notes: String?, workoutDiary: WorkoutDiary, weight: Int) {
    self.name = name
    self.notes = notes
    self.workoutDiary = workoutDiary
    self.currentWeights.heavy = weight
}

// MARK: Types

// weights of the exercise
struct Weights {
    var heavy = 0
    var warmup25: Int { return roundToFives(Double(heavy) * 0.25) }
    var warmup50: Int { return roundToFives(Double(heavy) * 0.50) }
}

struct PropertyKey {
    static let nameKey = "Exercise_name"
    static let notesKey = "Exercise_notes"
    static let workoutDiaryKey = "Exercise_workoutDiary"
    static let currentWeightsHeavyKey = "Exercise_currentWeightsHeavy"
}

func recordWorkout(date: String, weight: Int, repsFirstSet: Int, repsSecondSet: Int) {
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yy-MM-dd"

    let newSets = [Set(weight: weight, repCount: repsFirstSet),Set(weight: weight, repCount: repsSecondSet)]
    let newWorkoutLogEntry = Workout(date: dateFormatter.dateFromString(date)!, sets: newSets)
    workoutDiary.addWorkout(newWorkoutLogEntry)

    //update weights
    self.currentWeights.heavy = weight
}

func getLastWorkout() -> Workout? {
    if let workout = workoutDiary.getLastWorkout() {
        return workout
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}

func getOldestWorkoutFromRange(dateRange: Int? = nil) -> Workout? {
    return workoutDiary.getOldestWorkoutFromRange(15)
}

func getBarWeightsString(targetWeight: Int) -> String {
    if targetWeight < 54 {
        return "Bar"
    } else {
        return calculatePlates(roundToFives(Double(targetWeight)))
    }
}

func getTotalVolumeIncrease(dateRange: Int) -> Int {
    let perfAnalyzer = PerformanceAnalyzer()
    return perfAnalyzer.calcTotalVolumeIncrease(workoutDiary, dateRange: dateRange)
}

// MARK: NSCoder

func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encodeObject(name, forKey: PropertyKey.nameKey)
    aCoder.encodeObject(notes, forKey: PropertyKey.notesKey)
    aCoder.encodeObject(workoutDiary, forKey: PropertyKey.workoutDiaryKey)
    aCoder.encodeInteger(currentWeights.heavy, forKey: PropertyKey.currentWeightsHeavyKey)
}

required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    let name = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(PropertyKey.nameKey) as! String
    let notes = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(PropertyKey.notesKey) as! String?
    let workoutDiary = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(PropertyKey.workoutDiaryKey) as! WorkoutDiary
    let currentWeights = aDecoder.decodeIntegerForKey(PropertyKey.currentWeightsHeavyKey)

    // Must call designated initializer.
    self.init(name: name, notes: notes, workoutDiary: workoutDiary, weight: currentWeights)
}
}
```

My Controller:

```
class ExerciseDetailViewController: UIViewController  {

@IBOutlet weak var display: UILabel!

// This value is either passed by `ExerciseTableViewController` in `prepareForSegue(_:sender:)`
var exercise: Exercise?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    displayExercise()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func displayExercise() {
    if let exercise = exercise {
        navigationItem.title = exercise.name

        let currentWeights = exercise.currentWeights
        let warmup25Text = String(currentWeights.warmup25) + " " + exercise.getBarWeightsString(currentWeights.warmup25)
        let warmup50Text = String(currentWeights.warmup50) + " " + exercise.getBarWeightsString(currentWeights.warmup50)
        let heavyText = String(currentWeights.heavy) + " " + exercise.getBarWeightsString(currentWeights.heavy)

        if let notes = exercise.notes {
            display.text! = "Notes:\n"
            display.text! += "\(notes)\n"
            display.text! += "\n"
        }

        display.text! += "Warmup (25%): \(warmup25Text)\n"
        display.text! += "Warmup (50%): \(warmup50Text)\n"
        display.text! += "Heavy (100%): \(heavyText)\n"
        display.text! += "\n"

        if let lastWorkout = exercise.getOldestWorkoutFromRange(15) {
            display.text! += "\(NSDateToPrettyString(lastWorkout.date)) Reps @\(lastWorkout.sets[0].weight): \(lastWorkout.sets[0].repCount) and \(lastWorkout.sets[1].repCount)\n"
        }

        if let lastWorkout = exercise.getLastWorkout() {
            display.text! += "\(NSDateToPrettyString(lastWorkout.date)) Reps @\(lastWorkout.sets[0].weight): \(lastWorkout.sets[0].repCount) and \(lastWorkout.sets[1].repCount)\n"
            display.text! += "\n"
            display.text! += "15-day total volume increase: \(exercise.getTotalVolumeIncrease(15))%"
            display.text! += "\n"

        }

    }
}
}
```

Workout class, part of my model, a core data structure used by WorkoutDiary, which is stored in Exercise:

```
class Workout: NSObject, NSCoding {
var date: NSDate
var sets: [Set]

init(date: NSDate, sets: [Set]) {
    self.date = date
    self.sets = sets
}

struct PropertyKey {
    static let dateKey = "Workout_date"
    static let setsKey = "Workout_sets"
}

func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encodeObject(date, forKey: PropertyKey.dateKey)
    aCoder.encodeObject(sets, forKey: PropertyKey.setsKey)
}

required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    let date = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(PropertyKey.dateKey) as! NSDate
    let sets = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(PropertyKey.setsKey) as! [Set]

    self.init(date: date, sets: sets)
}

}
```

Here is where the Workouts live:

```
class WorkoutDiary: NSObject, NSCoding {
var diary: [Workout] = []

init(diary: [Workout]) {
    self.diary = diary
}

struct PropertyKey {
    static let diaryKey = "WorkoutDiary_diary"
}

func addWorkout(workout: Workout) {
    diary.append(workout)
}

func getLastWorkout() -> Workout? {
    return diary.last
}

func getOldestWorkoutFromRange(dateRange: Int? = nil) -> Workout? {
    // if diary is empty, return nil
    if diary.count == 0 {
        return nil
    }

    // if an argument was passed
    if let dateRange = dateRange {
        let daysAgo = calcDaysAgo(dateRange)

        // iterate through Diary in reverse to find first workout that is older than dateRange
        for workout in diary.reverse() {

            // find the first workout that is older than our dateRange
            if workout.date < daysAgo {

                // if that workout happens to be our last workout, return nil
                if workout == diary.last {
                    return nil
                }

                // otherwise, return the workout just ahead of the matched workout
                return diary[diary.indexOf(workout)!+1]
            }
        }

        // if we don't find any workouts that are older than our range, return the first
        return diary.first
    } else {

        // if no argument, just return the first element
        return diary.first
    }
}

func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encodeObject(diary, forKey: PropertyKey.diaryKey)
}

required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    let diary = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(PropertyKey.diaryKey) as! [Workout]

    self.init(diary: diary)
}
```

Comment: Instead of telling us about your code and providing links to your code, you should include your actual code.  And with that said, if you actually want a review of your actual code, you should consider whether [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) might be a more appropriate venue.

Comment: Sorry.. new to the site.  Your comments make sense.  I've added more code inline.  Thanks for the guidance.